# React Unable to access state property - Not found solution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to access a state property (from Apple Music API) but I'm getting the error 'Cannot read properties of undefined'. I followed all the suggestions found but no success.

Case: I'm using arrow function (no need of bind).
The state has been initialized.
I can read the whole object (collection) or single (collection[0]) but not it's property (collection[0].artistName).

Does anyone can give me a light?

**state:collection[0]**

```
{
    "wrapperType": "collection",
    "collectionType": "Album",
    "artistId": 91853,
    "collectionId": 190173909,
    "amgArtistId": 62404,
    "artistName": "Mariah Carey",
    "collectionName": "Greatest Hits",
    "collectionCensoredName": "Greatest Hits",
    "artistViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/artist/mariah-carey/91853?uo=4",
    "collectionViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/greatest-hits/190173909?uo=4",
    "artworkUrl60": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/bf/5f/21/bf5f21bf-f65e-532a-9c63-58f6900ec28e/source/60x60bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl100": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/bf/5f/21/bf5f21bf-f65e-532a-9c63-58f6900ec28e/source/100x100bb.jpg",
    "collectionPrice": 14.99,
    "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
    "trackCount": 28,
    "copyright": "℗ This compilation (P) 2001 Sony Music Entertainment",
    "country": "USA",
    "currency": "USD",
    "releaseDate": "2001-12-03T08:00:00Z",
    "primaryGenreName": "R&B/Soul"
}
```

**code**

```html
class Album extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      collection: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchSearchAlbum();
  }

  fetchSearchAlbum = async () => {
    const { match: { params: { id } } } = this.props;
    const data = await getMusics(id);
    this.setState({ collection: data });
  }

  render() {
    const { collection } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <div data-testid="page-album">
          <h1>Album</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p data-testid="album-name">{collection[0].collectionName}</p>
            <p data-testid="artist-name">{collection[0].artistName}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <MusicCard />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>

    );
  }
}

Album.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number,
}.isRequired;

export default Album;
```

Comment: try `{collection[0]? collection[0].artistName: null}`

Comment: by what you're saying it should work, but you have to provide a reproducible example in https://stackblitz.com/ or https://codesandbox.io, so we could help you more

Comment: Have you confirmed the result from the API call, within the `fetchSearchAlbum`? May be try adding a console after 'data' is populated to view the items. [Not to be confused with invoking the API externally, such as via postman, etc].

One possible way to avoid the error is to use `(collection[0] || {}).artistName`. Or, may be: `collection[0]?.artistName`.

Comment: @MWO your solution was the first and did the job! Thank you! please post it as an answer, then I choose it as solved.

Comment: @KelsonBatista ok glad i could have helped you out. posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `collection` is being fetched after `ComponentDidMount` and is an empty array at first. So you have to make sure `collection` is defined before trying to access it like so:

```
{collection[0]? collection[0].artistName: null}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the fact "collection" is an empty array prior to the getMusics request which is an async call. It takes time for the request to complete and your state to update.

It cannot find a value at collection[0] as it's undefined.

A simple solution would be to check the length of the collection array before returning your component, like so:

```
const { collection } = this.state;

if (collection.length === 0) {
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Render is called before ComponentDidMount, also you are calling an asynchronous function.

So, just like jsNoob write:

```
<p data-testid="album-name">{collection[0]?.collectionName}</p>
<p data-testid="artist-name">{collection[0]?.artistName}</p>
```